# Coger valores de una lista con jquery

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo los siguientes datos.

Dos etiquetas **p** con un nombre y una edad.
Después tengo una lista con ciertos valores.

Con jquery cojo el nombre y el usuario sin problema. Pero no se como coger todos los valores de la lista, imagino que necesito un bucle.

```
 <p class="name"> User </p>
 <p class="age"> 99 </p>
 <ul>
   <li> item1 </li>
   <li> item2 </li>
   <li> item3 </li>
   <li> item4 </li>
 </ul>
```

Una vez conseguidos todos lo datos agradecería que metodologia o que se usa en js para crear un json con dichos datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estás usando jQuery, puedes usar el método **[.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)**. Precisamente en su documentación, ponen un ejemplo como el que tú necesitas:

```
$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});
```

Con el selector `$("li")` obtienes un array con todas las etiquetas `<li>`, y con el método `.each()` iteras sobre cada uno sus elementos.

La función anónima que le pasas al método `.each()` puede tener dos parámetros: *index* y *element*, así que podrías reescribir lo anterior de esta otra manera:

```
$( "li" ).each(function( index, element ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + element.innerHTML );
});
```

... siendo *index* el índice del array que estás iterando y *element* cada uno de los `<li>`. Puedes usar otras propiedades del element `<li>` en vez de **innerHTML**, como **innerText**, **outerText** o **textContent**.